# Kotlin, Как ограничить число одновременно выполняемых корутин

Tags: kotlin, map, coroutine

Задача такая - обработать большой список объектов параллельно, но чтобы одновременно работали не более определенного количества обработчиков.

Например есть такой вариант:

```
fun <A, B>List<A>.pmap(f: suspend (A) -> B): List<B> = runBlocking {
    map { async(CommonPool) { f(it) } }.map { it.await() }
}
```

Но тут будет обработка всего списка одновременно.

Как бы сделать этакую аналогию `delayWhen` из  `RxJava`?

```
var i:Int = 0; //atomic
onEach { i++ } }
    .delayWhen{ i > 9 }
    .map{ async(CommonPool){ e -> { doSomeStuff(e) } } }
    .map { it.await() }
    .onEach { i-- }
```

Может вообще тут другой подход нужен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так

```
suspend fun <T, R> List<T>.runParallel(maxThreads:Int, worker: (T) -> R): List<R> {
    val out = ArrayList<R>()
    val processThreads = Math.min(maxThreads, size)
    val processingContext = newFixedThreadPoolContext(processThreads, "process-context")
    val waitingTasksChannel = Channel<T>()
    val finishTasksChannel = Channel<R>()
    val schedulingTask = launch {
        this@runParallel.forEach {
            waitingTasksChannel.send(it)
        }
    }
    val processingTasks = (1..processThreads).map {
        launch(processingContext) {
            for (waitTask in waitingTasksChannel) {
                val processResult = worker(waitTask)
                finishTasksChannel.send(processResult)
            }
        }
    }
    val finishTask = launch {
        for (finishTask in finishTasksChannel) {
            out.add(finishTask)
        }
    }

    schedulingTask.join()
    waitingTasksChannel.close()
    processingTasks.forEach { it.join() }
    finishTasksChannel.close()
    finishTask.join()
    return out
}
```